# Issue converting obj (3d) to png

Tags: php, three.js

I am having trouble with converting my `.obj` files displayed with **`three.js`** on my website to png. I feel like having it display raw obj files that are pannable lacks quality on my website and has limitations so I am trying to convert it to a png image. Any suggestions with doing so?

Comment: Why do you feel it lacks quality? I ask because rather than have this flagged as a duplicate, you could re-word your question to express specifically what you're seeing/not seeing, and we could potentially help you fix what you find lacking.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out the ambient made it look extremely poor. I've added a toggle and they both look great.